Are there any LTspice models for OP AMPS with GHz bandwidth?
I would like to try experimenting with op amps to use as buffers for oscillators. I know op amps exist for such applications because I have found them but none of them have LTspice models. Let me know if you know of any models that have SPICE models? thank you.

if you're using LTspice, look at LT's catalog. They have a number of op amps with GBP > 1 GHz, and nearly every LT part has a model already included in a standard install of LTspice..

you mean the op amps that are already built into the LTSPICE software?

@help_me_learn Yes. Part of the whole point of providing LTspice to the public for free was to sell parts! Pretty much everything sold by LT (or AD, one might hope, though that acquisition was 8 yrs ago) should be there. And almost nothing by TI should be there. ;)

@help_me_learn Get onto Digikey, search for opamps, then select the GBP you want, select active only, and select Analog Devices as the source. Then find something there and look for the model in LTspice. Not all, perhaps, but many of them will likely be in there.

To further the last comment, I've already found the following that are built into LTspice: LTC6253-7, LTC6268-10, LTC6268-10, LT6230-10, LT6200-10.  And I'm using an old version of LTspice.  The latest could have even more.

You will get opamps with GhZ BW. This is one of them.
Spice models are available at "Tools & Simulations 2" section.
You can import that spice models to Ltspice
